# AJAX code runs multiple times with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

This does not happen every time I submit the form but every several times I submit it the AJAX submits the form/runs the ajax again. How can I change the following code to prevent this from happening.

```
$('.like_form').submit(function submitter() {
var data = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: "../like.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {   

        var comment_id = data.slice(-3);
        data = data.substring(0, data.length -3);
    jQuery.trim(comment_id);
        $('#comments_'+comment_id).html(data);
        $('.like_form').submit(submitter); // rebind submit



    },
    error: function(){
        alert('ERROR');
    }
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: `$('.like_form').submit(submitter); // rebind submit` why? This would result in existing forms having the same event bound multiple times, resulting in the ajax being sent multiple times.

Comment: @KevinB is that what is causing the problem

Comment: depends on whether you are replacing the original form, or just adding more.

Comment: @KevinB I am replacing the original form

Comment: in that case it *shouldn't* cause the problem you are seeing, but it still seems like the most likely candidate. I would remove that line and use event delegation.

Comment: are there more than one of these in page?

Comment: @charlietfl no that is the only one

Comment: Nothing in code shown would cause it to submit more than once

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not check if the function ajax is already in process. Adding a condition will prevent multiple submits

```
$('.like_form').submit(function submitter() {

    if($(this).data('submitting') == true) return; //return if ajax in progress
    $(this).data('submitting',true);

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../like.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {   
            var comment_id = data.slice(-3);
            data = data.substring(0, data.length -3);
            jQuery.trim(comment_id);
            $('#comments_'+comment_id).html(data);
            $(this).data('submitting',false);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('ERROR');
            $(this).data('submitting',false);
        }
   });
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding events with handlers is cumulative, meaning this binding you do in the success callback will be additional to the original binding:

> $('.like_form').submit(submitter);

This is stated in the [jQuery docs on event hanlders](https://api.jquery.com/bind/#event-handlers):

> As of jQuery 1.4.2 duplicate event handlers can be bound to an element instead of being discarded.

You would benefit from the [jQuery *one* method](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

> The .one() method is identical to .on(), except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation.

So your code would look like this, changing `.submit(` to `.one('submit',` at the two places where you have it:

```
$('.like_form').one('submit', function submitter() {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../like.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {   
            var comment_id = data.slice(-3);
            data = data.substring(0, data.length -3);
            jQuery.trim(comment_id);
            $('#comments_'+comment_id).html(data);
            $('.like_form').one('submit', submitter); // rebind submit
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('ERROR');
            $('.like_form').one('submit', submitter); // rebind submit
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

... and now your code comment is right:

```
 // rebind submit
```

I added a line in the above code to rebind the handler also in the *error* callback, so the user could retry.